# Vue Select Error on selection

Tags: vue.js, html-select

So I have got two select elements filled with Vue Model. The two items are next to each other inside the app scope.

```html
<div>
<select id="filterSelect" v-model="strings.testOptions">
    <option v-for="option in strings.testOptions" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
<select id="testFilter" v-model="strings.RBCrops" class="data">
     <option v-for="option in strings.RBCropsOptions" v-bind:value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Select values are set with localization files.

```js
{ 
  …
  testOptions:[
    {text:'A', value:'-'}
  ],
  RBCropsOptions: [
    { text: 'Bottom Right', value: 'RB' },
    { text: 'Bottom Only', value: 'B' },
    { text: 'Right Only', value: 'R' },
    { text: 'None', value: 'N' }
  ],
  …
}
```

In both case, values display fine when user click on the select element. 
[image]
However on mouseup, one of the two select doesn't display the selected value and remains blank. Plus, it's not possible to edit select anymore without reloading the page.
[image]

It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I did not see you declared `strings.RBCrops`  (`v-model="strings.RBCrops"`)?

Comment: I declared Vue instance in a js file (var app = new Vue…) and defined some props like data:{strings:{}}; strings are then loaded at startup depending on user language.Really the two select lay on the same declarations and tools.

Comment: what library you are using for **select**? could you post one MCV example?

Comment: Just old plain html select which options are set with Vue. I wish i could share code but it seems like I can't send another answer myself and I can ind a place to expose my code. Shall I zip it and place somewhere ?